# How to insert values to second row if first row is not empty? Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I should insert value to `parnerCode2` if `parnerCodeOwner1` already taken value;

Below code only inserts to `parnerCodeOwner1` if new values comes it rewrites first one, It shouldn't rewritten, value should inserted to `parnerCode2`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['partnerCode'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $partnerCode= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['partnerCode']);
    if (empty($partnerCode)) { 
        array_push($errors, "CODE required"); 
    }

    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM refer WHERE partnerCode='$partnerCode' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "update refer set partnerCodeOwner1= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'  where randomfield='$partnerCode'  ";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
    }   
}
?>
```

```
ID       randomfield   parnerCode2  parnerCodeOwner1
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   1   | uOxerUg4    |             | BuBI9vk        |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   2   | cZzuJlcs    |             | uOxerUg4       |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   3   | BuBI9vke    |             | cZzuJlcs       |
+-------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: What's the problem in adjusting your code to check first and then run either an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` query?

Comment: well @NicoHaase **race conditions** maybe? Ideally the topicstarter should merge these two queries into one if possible.

Comment: Race conditions are a good starting point for trouble, you're right. But as far as I read the given code and the table structure, defining whether the column is named `partnerCode` as used in the PHP code or `parnerCode2` as given in the table dump is another problem that should be solved first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started on the right track with this code:

```
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM refer WHERE partnerCode='$partnerCode' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

What you actually want is to grab the row that belongs to the user, not the partner. So, your query should be:

```
$user_check_query = "SELECT partnerCode1 FROM refer WHERE randomField='".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 1";
```

Once you get the $user row...

```
if(empty($user['partnerCode1']))
```

If that is true, insert the partnerCode into partnerCode1. Else, insert it into partnerCode2.

Also, there is no need to fetch the row to check it if there is an error. So, all of that code should come after the if statement that checks for errors.